# how can i edit a table view section header ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Im using a table view controller with headers for each of my three sections. I want to be able to change the look of the headers what would be the best way to do that.

something similar to how snapchat stories page headers look

Comment: Post more details, code or screenshot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can customise your section header by create customised `UITableViewCell` in storyboard.

You design 3 section as same as like snapshot in storyboard.

Here is the example of two section with two different `UITableView` cells I used

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {    
 //Say 2 section with two different look
 if section == 0{
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderTableViewCell1")! as! HeaderTableViewCell1
    header._lblGroupName.text = ""
    header._btnExpand.addTarget(self, action: "hideSection:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    header._lblTotalCount.text = ""
    return header.contentView
 }
 else{
   let header = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderTableViewCell2")! as! HeaderTableViewCell2
    header._lblGroupName.text = ""
    header._btnExpand.addTarget(self, action: "hideSection:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

    header._lblTotalCount.text = ""
    return header.contentView
 }
}
```

Create two custom `UITableViewCell` classes. Set the outlet

```
class HeaderTableViewCell1: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var _lblTotalCount: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var _btnExpand: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var _lblGroupName: UILabel!

}

class HeaderTableViewCell2: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var _lblTotalCount: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var _btnExpand: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var _lblGroupName: UILabel!

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the implications are of using cells for this, but I think you should be subclassing `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`. And `UITableView` has an accompanying `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier:)` function.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom view for your header, register it with either:

```
- (void)registerNib:(nullable UINib *)nib forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;

- (void)registerClass:(nullable Class)aClass forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
```

and customise it in:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section;
```

UPD:

Swift versions:

Register your nib in `viewDidLoad`:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
     tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "YourNibName", bundle:nil),               forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier: "YourIdentifier")
   }
```

Implement `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int)
```

and customise the `view` in there

Comment: thank you for the response im having a tough time really understanding this - anyway you could write in swift

Answer (score 0):

Just add this and do your required customization

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.size.width, height: tableView.sectionHeaderHeight))
    // Do your customization

    return view
}
```

Comment: Note: You should subclass UITableViewHeaderFooterView and return that. I wouldn't bother using a frame either. You should state the height as a constant under `tableView.sectionHeaderHeight` or implement `tableView(_:heightForHeaderInSection:)`

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let  headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("HeaderCell") as! CustomHeaderCell
    headerCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyanColor()

    switch (section) {
    case 0:
      // Do your customization
      //return sectionHeaderView
    case 1:
      // Do your customization
      //return sectionHeaderView
    case 2:
      // Do your customization
      //return sectionHeaderView
    default:
      //return sectionHeaderView
    }

    return headerCell
  }


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 40))
    footerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    return footerView
  }
```